# Export data from Orange-API

Tags: orange-api

I would like to know if it's possible to, automatically, export the data of an object from the Orange-API to AWS ? If so, how ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Orange API are you using ? If you use Live Objects IOT platform you have several means to get Data from an external system:

- Pull: Get Data thanks to HTTP REST API (Datastore or Search)
- Push: Push http from Live Objects to an external webhook
- Push: Connect your system to Live Objects with MQTT protocol to consume data in real time

Hop this helps